# Property decorator - different setter and getter types

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below decorator has been used only as a simple example. Do not try to figure out whether it has sense or not, please.

```
export function ToString(target: Object, key: string) {
  let parsedValue: string;

  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get: () => parsedValue,
    set: (value: number) => parsedValue = number.toString()
  });
}
```

As you see, above decorator takes 'number' as a parameter and in final step returns the same value but parsed to string.

set type -> number, get type -> string

unfortunately below notation is wrong

```
class TestClass {
  @ToString parsedValue: string = 5; // number is not assignable to string
}
```

We know that `ToString` decorator will parse the value but we can't type decorated property as string.

The workaround would be to pass the setter value to the decorator like this:

```
export function ToString(value: number) {
  return (target: Object, key: string) {
    let parsedValue: string;

    Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
      get: () => parsedValue,
      set: (value: number) => parsedValue = number.toString()
    });
  }
}

class TestClass {
  @ToString(5) parsedValue: string; // it's okay because we don't use setter here
}
```

Everything would be okay unless we want to use `this` context while passing value to the decorator.

```
class TestClass {
  @ToString(this.someService.value) parsedValue: string;

  constructor(private someService = {value: 5}) {
  }
}
```

`this` is undefined at this stage. Is there a way to achieve expected result without using `any` type? :)

Comment: This is really weird, you're overwriting the type system by using property that have different type in getter and in setter. You want `a.foo = 10; var x: string = a.foo + "foo"` to compile. I think that the only way is to use `(string | number)` type for that property.

Comment: Typescript doesn't support decorators changing types yet, it's still an open feature.